# Providing external voltage to a motor connected to arduino

Tags: arduino, motor

I am a noob in electronics . I am just learning it bit by bit. The below is my connection.

[image]

As you can see pin 13 is connected to one terminal of the motor and the other terminal of the motor is connected to the 5V source of the arduino. My motor is a 9v motor and hence I would like to operate it at 9v so how can I do this? Help is appreciated .

Comment: I advise you to do some searching on this site, this has been solved so many times. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino+motor

Comment: Please for the love of Ohm, do not drive a motor with your Arduino's PWM pin directly. *gags and dies*

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is looking at a motor driver board like this [DRV8835 driver from Pololu](https://www.pololu.com/product/2135). Then you can connect your 9V source to the VIN pin, your arduino (via a resistor - 10k) to the EN/PH pins and a 3.3V or 5V supply from the Arduino to VCC, ground it, put 2 10nF caps between VIN and GND and VCC and GND and go.

Alternatively, you can use a transistor or a relay to do the same.

Comment: Thx for the reply I have an h-bridge  would I be able to use this?

Comment: An h-bridge allows your motor to switch direction, but it still uses the power from your arduino to drive the motor (5V in your example, and only a limited amount of current). You want to use a driver or a transistor or relay to have the Arduino control a much higher power circuit which in turn drives the motor.